# How to implement Two factor Authentication using Microsoft Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, two-factor-authentication

I have an MVC application and an API project that talks to my database. Right now how login works is that my MVC application sends a username and password to my API. API then validates it and if it is valid, it uses Owin server to create a claim and generate a Bearer Token. In all subsequent requests, this token is passed and that's how my API identifies if the request is valid or not and based on that it fetches data from the database.

I now want to use Microsoft Owin's out of the box feature to support two-factor authentication. I read many articles on the same and most of them talk about using there Role management stuff i.e. their users, roles table etc.
Some of the articles I see are below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

[How to implement two factor auth in Web API 2 using ASP.NET identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317473/how-to-implement-two-factor-auth-in-web-api-2-using-asp-net-identity/43321055)

Even after reading this article I do not have a clear direction on how to implement it and If I go down the route of implementing with custom storage i.e. as per my database structure I will have to implement their core components and that will too lengthy implementation.

Could someone please suggest me in the direction I should take? A working example would be a great help.

Comment: Just create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 with Local Users project and copy the code to your Web API 2 project. You will only need to get rid of the view-related code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the MVC5 template is of no help at all. it uses cookie authentication and the SignInManager, but in a Web API project with OAuth set-up, it doesn't work. I've been struggling with this for hours. What's ridiculous is that I can't seem to find ANY tutorials or resources on implementing 2FA with Web API 2 and Identity 2.

Comment: It looks like Web API 2 and Identity 2 are quite tightly coupled, so it's hard to add you own two factor authentication in between. I'm trying this myself as well, but have not succeeded yet.

Comment: @marijnz0r : Does anyone find the solutions ? I am stuck with same issue. I will be very thankful.